# bootstrap loading very slowly when I hit back button in the browser

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm importing bootstrap in css by adding the following lines.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

and I'm including these two gems in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
```

When I go from page to page by hitting a back button , bootstrap is not loading properly. First view without css styling loads then the view with css styling loads. when I remove those two lines of importing, it works perfectly fine. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing bootstrap , try to use twitter-bootstrap-rails. it will load properly, you can get this from https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails